# READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not assigned until application relaunch

Tags: android, android-external-storage, runtime-permissions

I'm creating an app the requires to read an xml file from the device storage on first launch straight after the installation.
I'm facing a problem where after asking 'Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' permission at runtime (and have it granted) the ' new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()).canRead()' always returns false until I relaunch the app.
After relaunch everything works fine but this is not what I need.
Weird thing is that after receiving the permission granted if I check whether the app has the permission set everything looks fine

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;  -> always returns true after granting the permission
```

this is my code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == AddServerFragment.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_READ_PREMISSION) {
        if (permissions.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Logger.log(LOG_TAG, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE + " has been granted", Log.VERBOSE);
            ((AddServerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getAttachedFragmentTag())).parseServerConfigFile();
        } else {
            Logger.log(LOG_TAG, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE + " has been denied", Log.INFO);
        }
        return;
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

ParseServerConfigFile()

```
void parseServerConfigFile() {
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) ||
            Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        File serverSetupFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getString(R.string.server_ini_file_name));
        ConfigureServerAsyncTask configureServerAsyncTask = new ConfigureServerAsyncTask(this);
        configureServerAsyncTask.execute(serverSetupFile);
    } else {
        Logger.log(LOG_TAG, "Storage not available at the moment", Log.INFO);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Storage not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Logcat:
07-21 10:34:55.320 25272-25272/com.mdmobile.cyclops V/LoginActivity: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE has been granted
07-21 10:36:01.277 25272-25335/com.mdmobile.cyclops V/FA: Using measurement service
    Connecting to remote service
07-21 10:36:01.290 25272-25335/com.mdmobile.cyclops V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 22213849
07-21 10:36:01.291 25272-25272/com.mdmobile.cyclops I/ConfigureServerAsyncTask: No ServerSetup.xml file found

Has anybody seen that before?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that one out.
Seems that it is required as that permission is a Linux permission.

Answer (score 0):

As in the article pointed by David Michael
Possible solution, though is very ugly (and looks like a bug) to see the app reloading once accepted the permission:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == AddServerFragment.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_READ_PREMISSION) {
            if (permissions.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Logger.log(LOG_TAG, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE + " has been granted \n app restart required",
                        Log.INFO);
                //READ STORAGE PERMISSION requires application restart as it is a linux permission
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                if (i != null) {
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            } else {
                Logger.log(LOG_TAG, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE + " has been denied", Log.INFO);
            }
            return;
        }
```